# Spring data JPA Hibernate - EntityManager.executeUpdate or spring repository both fails while using to query/update entity in multi-schema one by one

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

> We have multi-schema DB, and each schema contains algorithm_execution table  First I get the schema-list, and then prepare the update query for one-by-one in loop for each schema-name and run *EntityManager.executeUpdate()* which is failing with below error. Not sure what is the root cause as table exists in schema and I am able to run same update query on table using pgsql client.

> **Edit:**
> Tried to query/update the entity using spring data repository as well but that also fails. Can't we query a table on each schema one-by-one in for loop, before running the query we are specifying the schema in the context.

> The method that is failing -

**Code:**

```
private void updateJobStatus(EntityManager entityManager, String schemaName, AlgorithmExecution execution) throws Exception{
        try {
    private static final String UPDATE_JOB_STATUS_QUERY =   

            String updateQuery = "UPDATE "+schemaName+".algorithm_execution SET job_status = :job_status, modification_time = :modification_time, error_message = :error_message, job_logs = :job_logs WHERE id = :id";
            EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            entityManager.createNativeQuery(updateQuery)
                    .setParameter("job_status", execution.getJobStatus())
                    .setParameter("modification_time", execution.getModifiedTime())
                    .setParameter("error_message", execution.getErrorMessage())
                    .setParameter("job_logs", execution.getJobLogs())
                    .setParameter("id", execution.getId())
                    .executeUpdate();
            transaction.commit();
        } catch ( Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.warn("An exception occured during updateJobStatus, error {}", ex.getMessage());
            LOGGER.debug("An exception occured during updateJobStatus",ex);
            throw new Exception("An exception occured during updateJobStatus", ex);
        }
    }
```

> Hibernate internal logs below update query in the logs:
> *2020-12-15 12:11:28.159 +0000 [main] [DEBUG] -  org.hibernate.SQL [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger:logStatement:128] - update algorithm_execution set algorithm_checksum=?, algorithm_id=?, create_time=?, error_message=?, job_logs=?, job_name=?, job_status=?, job_summary=?, job_type=?, modification_time=?, next_execution=?, owner=?, previous_execution=?, start_time=?, tenant_id=? where id=?*

> Below is the exception stack trace -

**Exception:**

```
ava.lang.Exception: An exception occured during updateJobStatus
    at com.bmc.aif.jobmanager.jobmanagement.AIFJobManagementTask.updateJobStatus(AIFJobManagementTask.java:144)
    at com.bmc.aif.jobmanager.jobmanagement.AIFJobManagementTask.jobStatusFailedOrUnknown(AIFJobManagementTask.java:118)
    at com.bmc.aif.jobmanager.jobmanagement.AIFJobManagementTask.executeTasks(AIFJobManagementTask.java:79)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at com.bmc.aif.jobmanager.jobmanagement.AIFJobManagementTask.main(AIFJobManagementTask.java:149)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1356)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1339)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.beforeQuery(NativeQueryImpl.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1610)
    at com.bmc.aif.jobmanager.jobmanagement.AIFJobManagementTask.updateJobStatus(AIFJobManagementTask.java:139)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3430)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3292)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3704)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1352)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "algorithm_execution" does not exist
  Position: 8
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2532)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2267)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:312)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:153)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:119)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Did you set up you DB schema in Spring's Hibernate properties?
<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">SCHEMA_NAME</prop>

Or if you use spring boot then update application.properties as following:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema: my_schema

Comment: @Przemek This is multi-tenant system and each tenant has its own schema. The table algorithm_execution is available in each schema. Thus here are the steps - I am getting all schema list which contains relation by name algorithm_execution, and then preparing update query as per my above method to update the algorithm_execution table in each schema. So schema_name is not fixed it will be changed for each update query.  Do you see any issue with update query to run for each schema? If yes what should be the way to update algorithm_execution table in each schema in DB?

Comment: Found the root cause, We need to implement the interface MultiTenantConnectionProvider from hibernate and override methods getConnection and releaseConnection and specify schema name there. Without this hibernate was not able to understand the schema to be locked.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi,
> I am able to fix above issue using CrudRepository like -

```
@Repository
public interface AlgorithmExecutionRepository extends CrudRepository<AlgorithmExecution, UUID>


@Autowired
AlgorithmExecutionRepository executionRepository;

private void updateJobStatus(AlgorithmExecution execution)
            throws Exception {
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Set the RequestContext, the current tenant is {}", RequestContext.getCurrentTenant());
            LOGGER.info("updating the execution {} for jobId {} for status {} of tenant {}",
                    execution.getId(),execution.getAlgorithmId(), execution.getJobStatus(), execution.getTenantId());
            executionRepository.save(execution);
            LOGGER.info("Syccessfully updated the execution {} for jobId {} for status {} of tenant {}",
                    execution.getId(),execution.getAlgorithmId(), execution.getJobStatus(), execution.getTenantId());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.warn("An exception occured during updateJobStatus, error {}", ex.getMessage());
            LOGGER.debug("An exception occured during updateJobStatus", ex);
            throw new Exception("An exception occured during updateJobStatus", ex);
        }finally {
            RequestContext.clear();
            LOGGER.info("Cleared the RequestContext, the current tenant is {}", RequestContext.getCurrentTenant());
        }
        
    }
```

> Also, extended MultiTenantConnectionProvider to override the hibernate connection method. Need to set the schema and get the connection to that schema and then update the table.

```
    @Component
    public class TenantConnectionProvider implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {
    @Override
        public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            connection.close();
        }
    
        @Override
        public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
            logger.info("Get connection for tenant {}", tenantIdentifier);
            final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
            connection.setSchema(Constants.SCHEMA_PREFIX + "_" +tenantIdentifier.toUpperCase().trim());
            return connection;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            logger.info("Release connection for tenant {}", tenantIdentifier);
            releaseAnyConnection(connection);
        }
    
    }
```